# Jersey with tomcat giving 404 error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jersey

I am using Jersey with tomacat 6 and eclipse Juno.

my file name is HelloWorldService :

```
package com.mkyong.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

@GET
@Path("/{param}")
public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

    String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

  }

}
```

Web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

when i am running my project using Apache as server- it is going to this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/WEB-INF/classes/com/mkyong/rest/HelloWorldService.java
```

and i am getting 404 error.

I also tried with version="3.0" and it didn't work.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should give your url as follows;

```
http://localhost:8080/<your-war-name>/rest/hello/<your-param>
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer.   I created the war file and pasted it inside the apache folder then rub it using the url format given by you and it ran.   But i was wondering why it is not running inside the eclipse browser?   I am typing the url i used in the firefox in the eclipse browser but it is showing cannot start application.  Please me with that also if you can.   Thanks.

Comment: I have same issue. My Jersey sometimes does not work on J2EE preview server. But is working in Server. Can any give clue why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

The address for your example would be:

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/rest/hello/stranger
```

and this would output:

```
Jersey say : stranger
```

P.S. I guess your WAR name is Test.war and because that your deploy path is localhost:8080/Test

Comment: Why do people post duplicate answers?