# Jersey 2.x (Non Maven) gives 404 error when run on a Tomcat server

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, jersey-2.0

I've been trying to set up Jersey for my RESTful App and it's not going well. I don't prefer the maven method because i don't really understand the initial-maven-structure provided in the jersey documentation.. It contains a lot of additional dependencies that confuse and create problems.

So i set up a new simple web project in eclipse with tomcat server 7, and just to be sure, for the initial testing only, dumped all the jars in the build path.(though even for the basic jersey implementation, it requires a lot of jars, which is strange)

**The Question:**

**1)**
Having done all the above mentioned steps, when i start my tomcat server, it always gives me a 404 error.. The console doesn't show me an error, but it also doesn't show that `the server is live at http://localhost:8080/`

*P.S. I'm using the latest i.e 2.9 version of Jersey*

All my code & console output is as follows:

**Console when i start the server**

```
Jun 16, 2014 12:36:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/Sahil/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Jun 16, 2014 12:36:01 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
Jun 16, 2014 12:36:01 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:REST test' did not find a matching property.
Jun 16, 2014 12:36:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 16, 2014 12:36:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 16, 2014 12:36:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2339 ms
Jun 16, 2014 12:36:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 16, 2014 12:36:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
Jun 16, 2014 12:36:06 AM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.9 2014-05-22 05:12:10...
Jun 16, 2014 12:36:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 16, 2014 12:36:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 16, 2014 12:36:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4117 ms
```

**WEB.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>REST test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sahilgandhi</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**and just another test class**

```
package com.sahilgandhi.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.sahilgandhi.data.User;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "testapi" path)
 */
@Path("testapi")
public class TestApi {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "works like a dream!!"; // I HOPE IT DID! :(
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How silly of me, i didn't use the `war name` in the URL.. But i'll keep this code up for anyone who goes through the struggle of setting up jersey

**Answer to the question**

`http://localhost:8080/<your-war-name>/<your-servlet-URI>/<whatever>`

so for me it is-> `http://localhost:8080/REST_Test/rest/testapi`

Credits: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14644593/2654259)